# How do I create a jQuery UI Widget using TypeScript

Tags: typescript, jquery-ui-widget-factory

Help. I'm new to java script so thought I'd try using TypeScript to make my life a little easier.... but I cannot figure out where to start when trying to create a jquery UI Widget using TypeScript.

I've created UI Widgets in java script before and know that at its most basic I'm aiming for;

```
$.widget( "nmk.progressbar", {
  _create: function() {
    var progress = this.options.value + "%";
    this.element.addClass("progressbar").text( progress );
  }
});
```

(From the [jQuery UI Widget Factory](http://stage.learn.jquery.com/plugins/stateful-plugins-with-widget-factory/) tutorial)

Is it even possible to create a jquery UI Widget using TypeScript?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try if this helps..I know its not exactly answering your question but it worth taking a look..http://www.typescriptlang.org/Samples/#Warship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just need to reference the [jqueryui.d.ts](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jqueryui/jqueryui-1.9.d.ts) file from [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped) to get type information.

Comment: Of course! (Doh!)  I'd got it into my head that I needed to "export class".  I've been following DefinitelyTyped for a while. (Sammy, require, etc)